# Specifiying <K,V> type in `Pair<K,V>`

Tags: kotlin

How can I get rid of these `as String` casts?

What I want to do is to change the `fun` definition but I'm not sure how to do it... to include `String` in there

```
 parametersOf("appKey" to "asdas3334", "token" to "433432")

/**
 * Returns a new [Parameters] with the specified contents, given as a list of pairs
 * where the first component is the key and the second is the value.
 */
fun <K, V> parametersOf(vararg pairs: Pair<K, V>): Parameters {

    val p = Parameters(pairs.size)

    for ((key, value) in pairs)
        p.put(key as String, value as String)

    return p
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just get rid of the generic definition and use a `Pair<String, String>`:

```
fun parametersOf(vararg pairs: Pair<String, String>): Parameters {

    val p = Parameters(pairs.size)

    for ((key, value) in pairs)
        p.put(key, value) 

    return p
}
```